Why is GORM migration inferring the wrong data types for a many to many relationship?
I have the following structs generated by Gorm Gen:
type UserBase struct {
    ID         int32  `gorm:"column:id;primaryKey;autoIncrement:true" json:"id"`
    Name       string `gorm:"column:name" json:"name"`
}
type Account struct {
    ID         int32  `gorm:"column:id;primaryKey;autoIncrement:true" json:"id"`
    Name       string `gorm:"column:name" json:"name"`
}

I extend the UserBase struct to have a many to many relationship with Account, for pre-loading and migration purposes:
type User struct {
    UserBase
    Accounts []Account `gorm:"many2many:user_accounts"`
}

When I try and migrate the database to a clean MySQL database with no tables:
models := []interface{}{
    &Account{},
    &User{},
}
for _, model := range models {
    if err := db.Migrator().AutoMigrate(model); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error migrating model %v: %v\n", model, err)
    }
}

I get the following error:
Error 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint
[11.180ms] [rows:0] CREATE TABLE `user_account` (`user_id` int,`account_id` bigint unsigned,
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`account_id`),CONSTRAINT `fk_user_account_user` 
FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user`(`id`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_user_account_account` 
FOREIGN KEY (`account_id`) REFERENCES `account`(`id`))
Error migrating model &{{0  } []}: Error 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

Notice that when it infers the many to many table, it creates the account_id field as a bigint unsigned, which does not match the ID field in the account table, since it was generated matching the structs int32 declaration.
Why is it creating that account_id field in the joining table as the wrong type? Also, why is it then creating the user_id field in the joining table as the correct int type? Both ID fields are declared in the same way in the corresponding structs. Migrate also creates the User and Account tables in the database from the same struct, but there it uses the int datatype for the ID field in both tables. Where is it getting this unsigned bigint data type from?
